# Inconsistent crash while trying to add a persistent store in CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data, core-data-migration

I am facing a weird crash that happens on some devices, reported by Firebase and Xcode crashes history, while migrating to a new CoreData model. The only chan and adding 3 new propertiesge needed to be done is to remove a couple of properties in one table/object. I have regenerated the classes and upgraded the model version as it doesn't need but a light weight migration.

And all I am getting is:

```
crash_info_entry_0
Fatal error: Error migrating store: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 
"The file "<FileName>.sqlite" couldn't be opened." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/45859729-F07E-4006-8742-3B53DF6D1CE9/Documents/<FileName>.sqlite, NSSQLiteErrorDomain=23}: file /ProjectName/Repo/Models/Storage/CoreData/CoreDataEngine.swift, line 137
```

I am using Swift 4.2.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this problem? I face the exact same issue and have ran out of ideas how to debug it.

Answer (score 4):

SQLite error 23 is an [authorization error](https://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html). This probably means that you have data protection turned on in your app's capabilities (or else you're using `NSPersistentStoreFileProtectionKey` when loading the persistent store), and you're trying to access the persistent store when the file is not accessible (e.g. when the screen is locked).

If you can turn off data protection, that would solve the problem. If you need data protection, you need to use [data protection related methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforImplementingYourApp/StrategiesforImplementingYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW21) in your app delegate to detect when your app can safely access the file.

Comment: Actually store protection neither set in my app's capability nor while loading the store. It's a bit odd as I can only see the crash on Firebase. It crashes specifically here `addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: persistanceStoreURL, options: options)`